To fill variable names in panda dataframe
I have the below dataset and grouping the data as below:
inventory_data = {"item": ["LP","LP","LP","LQ","LQ","LQ","LM","LM","LM"],
        "B/A": ["B","B","B","A","A","B","B","A","A"],
        "qty": [9,10,11,12,13,13,13,14,210],
        "exp_date":["07-09-2025","15-09-2025","28-09-2024","01-09-2024","15-12-2025",
                    "07-12-2024","25-11-2025","07-10-2025","10-09-2025"]
        }

inventory_df=pd.DataFrame(inventory_data)
print(inventory_df)

  item B/A  qty    exp_date
0   LP   B    9  07-09-2025
1   LP   B   10  15-09-2025
2   LP   B   11  28-09-2024
3   LQ   A   12  01-09-2024
4   LQ   A   13  15-12-2025
5   LQ   B   13  07-12-2024
6   LM   B   13  25-11-2025
7   LM   A   14  07-10-2025
8   LM   A  210  10-09-2025

Then I am grouping the data and summing the "qty" column:
grouped_inventory_df=inventory_df.groupby(["item","B/A","exp_date"])["qty"].sum()
print(grouped_inventory_df)

item  B/A  exp_date
LM    A    07-10-2025     14
           10-09-2025    210
      B    25-11-2025     13
LP    B    07-09-2025      9
           15-09-2025     10
           28-09-2024     11
LQ    A    01-09-2024     12
           15-12-2025     13
      B    07-12-2024     13

May I ask, if I would like to fill in the blank with variable names with desired output below, how should I go about it? Million thanks for your help.
 item B/A  qty    exp_date
0   LM   A   14  07-10-2025
1   LM   A  210  10-09-2025
2   LM   B   13  25-11-2025
3   LP   B    9  07-09-2024
4   LP   B   10  15-09-2025
5   LP   B   11  28-09-2024
6   LQ   A   12  01-09-2024
7   LQ   A   12  15-12-2025
8   LQ   B   13  07-12-2024


set as_index=False within your groupby
